# Installing python-flask gives Error [python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1]

Tags: python-3.x, installation, flask

I'm a beginner in python's framework 'flask', i was following this [link](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) for the installation and demo App(to create virtual environment).

I'm using python 3.3.2 and on windows platform

```
 python virtualenv.py flask
```

the above command gets well executed and all the files are downloaded correctly but when i execute

```
 pip install flask==0.9
```

it gives me the following error

```
 Downloading/unpacking flask==0.9
 Downloading Flask-0.9.tar.gz (481kB): 481kB downloaded
 Running setup.py egg_info for package flask
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "D:\Technologies\flaskpython\flask\build\flask\setup.py", line 62
    print "Audit requires PyFlakes installed in your system."
                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

 File "D:\Technologies\flaskpython\flask\build\flask\setup.py", line 62

print "Audit requires PyFlakes installed in your system."

                                                        ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in D:\Technologies\fla
skpython\flask\build\flask
Storing complete log in C:\Users\wa\pip\pip.log
```

Please guide me to install it correctly

Comment: If I may suggest, use Python 2.7. You will save yourself a world of pain! http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/python3/.

Answer (score 3):

Any reason you want to install specifically version 0.9? Why not `pip install flask`, which will install the latest 0.10.1 and its dependencies for Python 3.3.x? I tried it and it worked fine in virtualenv, while installing version 0.9 gave me the same error than you.

HTH, Phil

Answer (score 0):

You can always got to pypi and download packages manually.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask

And then put the `flask` folder into the `C:\Python33\lib\site-packages`.

The problem you have is that the installer is not made for python3.

This makes me think that they did not prepare flask for python 3 which makes me guess that if you install flask under Python 3 you will have more problems. But you can try and be lucky.